# how to enable iPhone6+ screen resolution in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-6-plus

I am using Xcode 5 (iOS7) and now I want to develop an app, which should be compatible with all iPhone devices. Now using Xcode 5 and in Xcode 5 there is no resolution option for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+. How to enable these resolutions in Xcode 5?

1) Can I upgrade my Xcode 5 to 6?

2) Can I upgrade my mac from 10.9 to something?

3) How to upgrade splash screen for iPhone 6+?

4) Is it possible that I used Xcode 5 for both iPhone 5 and iPhone 6?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Xcode 6 to support iOS 8 APIs and to support native resolutions on the iPhone 6 and 6+.

Xcode 5 can't be used to support iOS 8 APIs nor native resolutions on the new iPhones.

---

1) Yes, install Xcode 6

2) Maybe. It depends on your Mac. But Xcode 6 works just fine on OS X 10.9.

3) Add iPhone 6 and 6+ launch images or use the new launch screen file.
(again: only works when you use the ios8 API in xcode6)

4) Sort of. Xcode 5 can be used with iOS 8 devices but only after the device has been used at least once with Xcode 6. And Xcode 5 can use the iPhone 6/6+ but not at their native resolutions. You need Xcode 6 for that.

Answer (score 1):

rmaddy answered this nicely, just adding additional information here:

1. You will have to upgrade sooner or later, so better to do it early. In addition you can keep Xcode 5 installed alongside Xcode 6.
2. Both Xcode 5 and 6 work on Mavericks (10.9) and Yosemite (10.10). If your Mac hardware supports the upgrade, you should upgrade, but it really depends on your personal preferences. It is not necessary for iOS 8.
3. Add appropriate resolution launch images for iPhone 6 (750 x 1334 - @2x) and iPhone 6+ (1242 x 2208 - @3x) or use mentioned launch screen XIB. Detailed description in document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html
4. You can run iOS 7 apps on iPhone 6 and 6+ in Xcode 5, but as previously mentioned, if the device has iOS 8 installed, Xcode 5 will not detect it unless Xcode 6 has already detected it. This means that you will not be able to run apps on iPhone 6 and 6+, without opening Xcode 6 at least once to process the device (there is no iPhone 6 with iOS7). This goes the same for iPhone 5(s/c) if they have iOS 8 installed.